# IAP GCIP integration results in HTTP 404 error on /config resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy

Trying to integrate Github OAUTH2 using Google Cloud Identity Platform and Identity Aware Proxy on GCP and Firebase UI deployed on Cloud Run (out-of-the-box). I have owner role for this account

Getting following error from browser console, when trying to access protected application. Redirection seems to be happening but the firebase UI is not shown.

> A specified resource is not found, or the request is rejected by
> undisclosed reasons

The resource url resulting in HTTP status 404 is https://iap-gcip-hosted-ui-app-engine-app-app-specific-code-de.a.run.app/config

Do I require any specific privilege besides the Owner role.
Below url is accessible, which is meant for configuring firebase UI

> https://iap-gcip-hosted-ui-app-engine-app-app-specific-code-de.a.run.app/admin

Comment: No, you need nothing mode, but it's not a authorization issue, but a ressource issue. Are you sure about the URL?

Comment: @guillaume - yes I am sure of the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bad reference to auth ui project. Reuploading auth ui project to the firebase hosting  (associated with gcp project) made it work

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar symptom, and the problem was that I didn't have any "Identity Providers" enabled other than "Anonymous", which the GCIP tool didn't know how to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).